# bind9 on server locally for mail ptr record with cloudflare as name servers

Tags: postfix, bind, reverse-dns, cloudflare, ptr-record

I am using cloudflare's name servers for `example.com` with a `cname` for `www` - these are filtered through cloudflare.

In cloudflare, I have an mx record pointing to `mail.example.com` and a `mail` A record pointing to the mail server's IP - which is not filtered through cloudflare.

Mail is working but going to spam in gmail. So I needed a ptr record which cannot be setup with cloudflare because they do not handle mail traffic.

I setup bind9 on the mail server with a ptr record and `dig -x [the mail server ip] @[the mail server ip]` successfully returns the ptr record for the mail server ip for `mail.example.com` in the answer section, but the rest of the web does not see this. I tested with the mxtoolbox reverse dns lookup and it still shows the amazon ec2 hostname instead of mail.example.com. Also test emails sent from thunderbird (authenticating to the smtp mail.example.com server) are still going to spam in gmail.

Is it possible to use cloudflare for `www.example.com` in combination with dns on the mail server for `mail.example.com` so that the ptr record for the mail server ip will work?

Comment: PTR records are based on IP address, there is no such thing as a PTR record for mail.example.com.  Only the organization that has authority delegated to them for the IP address in question can set a public PTR for the IP.

Comment: thank you, the ptr record for the mail server ip is setup and working but my wording was not exactly right there.

Comment: i have an elastic ip with amazon ec2. as far as i know we can setup the ptr record in bind9 on the server. the problem is that the name servers are with cloudflare instead of ns.example.com

Comment: I think you need to read up and understand how DNS delegation works, specifically with regards to in-addr.arpa.   Cloudflare should not be (or need to be) involved with this at all.  You need Amazon's IP's PTR updated.

Comment: Maybe my question was confusing or you didn't fully read it. I want to use cloudflare for www ddos protection. I know that they are not involved with the ptr record. Since they are the authoritative name server though, I don't believe my working dns ptr on the mail server is recognized. I believe switching away from cloudflare to just use ns.example.com would fix the problem, but then I will lose ddos protection on www

Comment: dig -x [the mail server ip] @[the mail server ip] does return mail.example.com ; but dig -x [the mail server ip] does not

Comment: Do you mean to say that even with a working dns setup on the mail server, amazon still has to setup the ptr record on their end?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you're being told.  The DNS servers for `example.com` have **absolutely nothing** to do with reverse DNS lookup of IP addresses via PTR records.

Comment: Well I figured it out and got it working as desired with no thanks to you guys. Cloudflare for www and bind9 server for mail with reverse dns working. I'm not going to share the solution with you douche bags though, you'll have to figure it out for yourselves. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the delegation of DNS records.

Cloudflare is hosting the example.com forward lookup zone.
The owner of the IP address (Amazon) is hosting the IP Address reverse lookup zone.

PTR records can ONLY be modified by the owner of the IP address which in this case is Amazon. You can move hosting of example.com to your own server, which is not recommended, and as you said, will defeat the protection CloudFlare gives you. But, that will only move the example.com forward lookup zone. It will not move the IP address reverse lookup zone.

To make a request to Amazon to update your PTR record, please see here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/

Comment: I got it working as desired but thank you.